# What is the correct syntax for deprecating a single constructor in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, deprecated

I am using the new [[deprecated("message")]] attributes in my code. I have a class that has two constructors, one of which should be marked as deprecated (obviously simplified, and possibly with syntax errors):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    // good constructor
    MyClass(int someNumber): _someNumber(someNumber) {}

    [[deprecated("Use MyClass(int) instead")]]
    MyClass(const char* someStr): _someNumber(atoi(someStr)) {}

private:
    int _someNumber;
}
```

Visual Studio complains that "attribute 'deprecated("Use MyClass(int) instead")' cannot be applied in this context.

Is there a way to deprecate a constructor in Visual Studio 2015 so that I get a warning if it is used anywhere?

Comment: Is that managed or regular C++?

Comment: @orhtej2 Regular C++

Answer (score 5):

Mark the parameter as deprecated:

```
MyClass([[deprecated]]const char* someStr){}
```

Or:

```
MyClass([[deprecated("Use MyClass(int) instead")]]const char* someStr){}
```

Or use [__declspec(deprecated)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx):

```
__declspec(deprecated("** Use MyClass(int) instead **"))
        MyClass(const char* someStr) : _someNumber(atoi(someStr)) {}
```

Also depending on your update version (no. 3) you might be experiencing [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2931827).